# How to convert C style printf to C++ style cout in vim

Tags: c++, vim

I got hand over some legacy code and first I want to see if it's possible to change something like

```
printf("test %d\n", var);
```

into

```
std::cout << "test " << var << std::endl;
```

There are a lot of them and doing them manually is very time consuming. Is there a way to use vim to make this happen?

The furthest I get is

```
:%s/printf(\(.*\), \(.*\));/std::cout << \1 << \2 << std::endl;/g
```

but this only gets me

```
std::cout << "test %d\n" << var << std::endl;
```

I can apply clang format to the code so in printf I can guarantee there is always a space after a comma. In this example the space is between comma and var.

Ideally this vim command would be able to detect the percentage sign to know how many variables is in there and also detect \n to know when to replace it with std::endl. Please advice.

Comment: Sounds like you rather want to run a perl script over the source.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not familiar with perl, is there already a perl script that does this already?

Comment: Are you able to use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/libs/format/)? If so, your conversion would be much more straightforward. `printf("test %d\n", var);` becomes `std::cout << boost::format("test %d\n") % var;`, so you don't have to change the format string at all.

Comment: I agree, perl is the appropriate solution here, and, no, I don't know of any perl script that does that, and I think it's unlikely that there is one, for a number of reasons.

Comment: If it's too complicated to use some one line of search and replace command in vim, would a vim macro be viable instead of switching to perl?

Comment: Or use Python. Hard-core users use sed. But I honestly would not trust some automatic tool to 100% succeed.

Comment: In addition to `Perl`, you can use unix `sed` if you have access to it or write C macros. The problem here we need to see all your `printf` lines to help you. If you need generic solution for any printf statements then it's painful. Also, vim's regex is powerful too. If you don't know either of `Perl` or `sed`, then open vim's regex tutorials and try again and again.

Comment: @lllllllllll: awk would also be an option.

Comment: \% is % ; \\ is \. You need to find \%d\\n
and delete it, and you will be done for your example.

Comment: Why do you even care?

Comment: Please note that while modern regex variants and dialect have evolved greatly over the original basic regex (now you can have backtracking and all kinds of funky stuff), no regex dialect that I know of can handle jumping back and forth between matches, so if you find a match in the formatting string, you can't get the corresponding match in the arguments. Also, using regexes [just gives you another problem](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try writing a macro.

First, A macro to convert the "%[insert here]" to the cout format.

```
:reg
--- Registers
"f   0f%2xmcf"f,dwdw`ci" << ^[pa << "^[
```

So what this does on macro key F, is

1. `0f%` Go to the start of the line, find the first percentage sign (assumes % is not used in any other way, sadly)
2. `2xmc` Delete the `%d` part, then store the current position in the line on marker c.
3. `f"f,` Find the end of the string, then find the first comma.
4. `dwdw` Delete the comma, then delete the variable name. This will allow the variable to be stored so it can be pasted later.
5. `[backtick]c` Go to the stored position in the line at mark c.
6. `i" << ^[` Insert `" <<` into the string and escape back to command mode.
7. `pa << "^[` Paste the stored variable name, then insert the string `<< "`.

So, the end result is this

```
printf("test %d\n", var); // Before
printf("test " << var << "\n"); // After
```

On another macro key R, simply replay macro F multiple times (say 100). It won't finish the macro if you have less than 100 variables because `f%` will fail.

```
:reg
--- Registers
"r   100@f
```

So, an example would be

```
printf("test %d %d %d %d %d\n", var, var1, var2, var3, var4); // Before
printf("test " << var << " " << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << "\n"); // After
```

Now write a macro C to convert the start and end to C++!

```
:reg
--- Registers
"c   0trcwcout << ^[f(x$F)x
```

1. `0tr` Go to start of line, and find UNTIL first r. This is in case of different indentation levels. We will be positioned at the `p` in `printf`.
2. `cwcout << ^[` Change `printf` to `cout <<` and escape to command mode.
3. `f(x` Find the `(` in `printf(` and delete it.
4. `$F)x` Go to the end of the line, find the last `)` and delete it.

This gives:

```
printf("test " << var << " " << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << "\n"); // Before
cout << "test " << var << " " << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << "\n"; // After
```

To tie it all together, make another macro T, which finds `printf`, runs macro C, then runs macro F. It is done in this order so that if an early part fails, the rest of the command won't run.

```
:reg
--- Registers
"t   /printf^M@c@r
```

Running this macro T 3 times does the following:

```
// Before
printf("test %d\n", var);
printf("test %d %d %d %d %d\n", var, var1, var2, var3, var4);
printf("test %d %d\n", var, var2);

// After
cout << "test " << var << "\n";
cout << "test " << var << " " << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3 << " " << var4 << "\n";
cout << "test " << var << " " << var2 << "\n";
```

This solution isn't perfect, it assumes there that percentages aren't used in any other format, and it has to be manually repeated for each printf (spamming `@@`). I hope it is at least useful, and shows the power of vim.

Comment: Sadly, macros don't work that way. Say, if we give `fx` and `x`, that is, finding x and delete that character. Even if x weren't there, fx will do nothing and the character where the cursor was (or mostly the first character) in a line will be deleted.

Comment: @SibiCoder I think you're missing the point. When you write a macro, this is true. You are first executing the command `fx`-"find x". Whether or not it exists, you will then run `x`-"delete character". However, once the macro is stored and you run it, it will again, run "find x". If x doesn't exist, it will fail, and the macro will stop, so the "delete character" will not actually run. Try it for yourself :)

Comment: In that case, the macro may break in any line where x doesn't exist. How to solve that?

Comment: This solution is very close to perfect for simple variable cases. Perhaps we need another macro to replace `\n` with `endl`?

Comment: @user3667089 Yeah, could use something like :%s/\"\(.*\)\n\"/\"\1\"\ <<\ endl;/g, which assumes that \n is at the end sadly. Can probably modify it to make it more generic, or such that it is part of the macro.

Comment: @SibiCoder The idea is that you don't want to run the macro if it does not contain x! In our code, we only want to run the code when we find "printf". If it does not exist, we have no need to convert to C++ I/O, so the macro shouldn't run.

Comment: You are right a simple search and replace should be enough. Bravo for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually harder than it seems, especially if you have more complicated formats with with field-width specifiers or other such things, or worse the `"%["` format. It is also complicated if the arguments to the format string are more complicated than simple variables or literals, for example if you have function calls.

However for ***simple*** formatting strings and arguments, such as the `printf` call shown in the question, it's not that hard to do in a script language. You get the formatting string and put it in a string variable, then you get all the arguments and put them as a string in another variable. Split the argument string on comma, and you have a list of the arguments.

Then iterate over the formatting string, and when you hit a `'%'` character, which is not followed by another `'%'` character, then print the formatting string up to that point and get the first argument from the list of arguments. Then continue to scan the formatting string and get each corresponding argument from its list when you hit a formatting sequence.

Comment: Is it "I don't know vim's regex so OP should learn something else?"

Comment: Fortunately the code I am handed to the arguments to the format string are all simple variables. Do you think it's still possible to do it with vim instead of switching to a scripting language?

Comment: For anything beyond really trivial cases, you need a fair bit more than a regex. Yes, it's probably possible with a bit of regex AND some programming. And I'd like to see someone try to solve `printf("%#f %F %18.2d \"quoted string\" *** ### %% %*s", 4.2, 93.46, 42, 10, "Hello, World");" - to parse that format string in C is a few hundred lines. And I don't mean translate it to "cout << 4.2 << 93.46 << 42 << "\"quoted string\"" << ...`, but the appropriate width and precision values and other formatting rules.

Answer (score 1):

I matched the `%d\n"` outside a capture and added a space and the closing " in the replacement.

```
:%s/printf(\(.*\) \S\+, \(.*\));/std::cout << \1 " << \2 << std::endl;/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer needs to be more generic!
So, we can use a vim function to detect both `%` characters like `%d%f%s` as well as escape sequence characters like `\n\r`.

Just a sample psuedocode.

```
        :function ConvertToCPP()
        :let a = getline('.')
        : while a doesn't contain % or \ characters
        :    take any number of  \n and put as endl at end of line, if any
        :   remove off the % characters.
        : put << in between each of them
        :   call setline ('.', a)
        :return 1
        :end function
```

Noe, you can call this function with range, such that it will easily replace them all.

```
    :10,20ConvertToCPP()
```